# Как найти все емайлы из массива с определенным значением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, email

Есть массив с 3000 и больше емайлами. Нужно найти все емайлы, начинающиеся с буквы `d` и заканчивающиеся, к примеру, по определённому домену, например, `@mail.ru` или `@gmail.ru`.

**Вопрос**: как это можно реализовать с помощью php?

**Update** намалевал быстро скрипт, но, так как у меня проблема с `preg_match()`, я не знаю, какой должен быть синтаксис для сравнения.

Учитывается, что все в массиве емайлы, а не просто значения:

```
$array_mail = array();
$new_mails = array();

foreach ($array_mail as $key => $value) {
    if ( /* preg_match(" незнаю, что здесь написать")  */) {
        $new_mails[] = $value;
    }
} 

echo "Это все емайлы, что были найдены!<br>";
foreach ($new_mails as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Перебрать все элементы, проверить что элемент начинается с того что вам нужно и оканчивается чем нужно.

Comment: А если мыло будет оканчиваться на `@mail.ru.test.com`, то его надо будет показывать в выборке по `@mail.ru`? Ведь `@mail.ru` присутствует

Comment: @BOPOH *и заканчивающиеся к примеру по определенному домену например @mail.ru*

Comment: как то я думаю можно все это прописать в preg_match и начало буквы и домен??

Answer (score 5):

Если исходный массив состоит только из e-mail без лишней текстовой обёртки, а в каждом элементе не более одного адреса, то лучше использовать обычные функции для обработки строк:

```
<?php
    $needful = array();

    // пробегаем по массиву всех адресов
    foreach ($all_mails as $all_mails_item) {
        // если текущий элемент начинается на d и заканчивается на gmail.com
        if ($all_mails_item{0} == 'd' && substr($all_mails_item, -9) == 'gmail.com') {
            // добавляем элемент в массив $needful
            array_push($needful, $all_mails_item);
        }
    }

    // вывод массива искомых электронных адресов
    print_r($needful);
?>
```

Они с задачей справятся быстрее, нежели регулярное выражение.

Comment: Вместо substr лучше использовать `ststr`

Comment: @u_mulder, соглашусь, с помощью `strstr()` будет проще. При этом я бы ещё `$all_mails_item` в `strtolower()` обернул.

Comment: Да, `strtolower` тоже хорошо

Answer (score 2):

Я не имел дело с PHP, так что не судите строго, но тем не менее я предложил бы все же использовать регулярное выражение. Дело в том, что буквы в почтовом адресе могут быть указаны в разных регистрах.

Шаблон может выглядеть следующим образом

```
/^d\S*@g?mail\.ru$/i"
```

Если есть какие-то расхождения с PHP, то, я думаю, этот шаблон легко можно будет подправить.

Данный шаблон проверяет как адреса, оканчивающиеся на @mail.ru (@Mail.Ru и т.д.), так и оканчивающиеся на @gmail.ru ( @Gmail.ru, @gMail.ru и т.д.)

Comment: есть же просто ключ `/i` чтобы игнорировать регистр: `/^d\S*@gmail\.com$/i`

Comment: @Sergiks Спасибо, буду знать.:)

Comment: Зря Вы думаете, что `[m|M]` это только м маленькая или М большая.

Comment: @ReinRaus А что это?

Comment: Это две буква м в двух регистрах и пайп `|`

Comment: @ReinRaus Да, правильно надо было написать (m|M).

Comment: Нет. Правильно было `[mM]`

Comment: @ReinRaus  Почему неправильно (m|M)?

Comment: Потому что для этого есть символьные классы, которые быстрее, чем альтернатива и не сохраняют группу.

Comment: @ReinRaus  Это не отменяет того, что это есть правильная запись. И я не знаю, насколько это быстрее. Я думаю, что это зависит от реализации.

Comment: Не суть. Так не пишут. Просто имейте ввиду на будущее :)

Answer (score 2):

Решение с помощью `array_filter`:

```
$required = array_filter(
    $source_array,
    function($v) {
        return $v[0] == 'd' && strstr($v, '@') == '@gmail.com';
    }
);
```

Comment: А вот это изящно.

Comment: Интересный подход не видел не разу, это типа тюплов в Swift только в PHP ???

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предпочёл [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-grep.php):

> `array preg_grep ( string $pattern , array $input [, int $flags = 0 ] )`
>   Возвращает массив, состоящий из элементов входящего массива **input**, которые соответствуют заданному шаблону **pattern**.
>
> В случае, если установлен в `PREG_GREP_INVERT`, функция `preg_grep()` возвращает те элементы массива, которые не соответствуют заданному шаблону **pattern**.

```
$array_mail = array('dartanian@gmail.ru', 'vasya@gmail.ru', 'dasha444@gmail.ru', 'don@mail.ru');
$result = preg_grep('/^d[^@]++@gmail\.ru$/i', $array_mail);
print_r(array_values($result));
```

`array_values()` возвращает массив с обновленной нумерацией элементов.

Если необходимо вернуть адреса и `gmail.ru`, и `mail.ru` регулярное выражение будет

```
'/^d[^@]++@g?mail\.ru$/i'
```

[Демо-код на IDEONE](http://ideone.com/YUujHZ)

Comment: А есть альтернатива file(); а то я емайлы вытаскиваю из файла функцией file а на сервере она запрещена

Comment: Может, [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php), а затем `explode()`?

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем то, что у меня получилось ниже логика скрипта должна быть такая:

- 1.Пользователь забивает в форму контакты (просто емайл контакты или контакты емайл:пароль или какая то другая вариация контактов. Скрипт разбивает это все на массивы и выявляет емаейлы и отделяет ненужное удаляя дубликаты. Сохраняет в файл все это дело.
- 2.Страница генерации позволяет сгенерировать базу из сохраненного файла по параметрам начального символа и конечного символа, а так же по домену и возможность скачать сгенерированный файл.
- 3.Страница позволяет отправить от указанного имени с темой и контентом письма всей базе сгенерированного файла.

Вот, что из этого получилось:

PS! не пинайте за быдло код лудше подправьте, что не так в нормальный код

```
class eMails extends mail
{

    protected $tmpFolder = "temp.txt";
    protected $genFolder = "generated.txt";

    function __construct($exec_time = 1600)
    {
        session_start();
        ini_set('max_execution_time', $exec_time); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        ini_set('display_errors',1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'us_US.UTF8');

        // Проверяем существуют папки для работы 

        if (!file_exists($this->tmpFolder)){
            $fh = fopen($newfile, 'w') or die("Невозможно ");
            fclose($fh);
        }

    }

    private function checkFiles($whatCheck=false){

        // Проверяем на существование и пустоту файл
        if (!file_exists($whatCheck) || '' == filesize($whatCheck)) {
            return false;
        } 
        return true;
    }

    private function getData($string=false,$getFromFile=false){

        if ($getFromFile)
            $string = file_get_contents($string);

        $array = array_filter(explode("\n", $string));

        if (count($array) < 1) {
            echo "Массив пустой, нечего обрабатывать!";
            return false;
        } 

        return $array;
    }

    public function addNewMails(){

        $count_processed= 0;

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

            /* Обрабатываем залитый файл и генерируем новый файл по определенному параметру */ 
            // Удаляем пустые массивы
            $_POST = array_filter($_POST);

            if ( !array_key_exists("data2load", $_POST) || empty($_POST['data2load'])) {
                die("<h3>Нет нужного параметра, выхожу...</h3>");
            }

            $_POST['data2load'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['data2load']);

            // Создаем массив с емайлами
            //$tmp = explode("\n", $_POST['data2load']);

            $tmp = $this->getData($_POST['data2load']);

            // Проверяем массив 
            if ($tmp != false) {

                /* Устанавливаем разделитель */
                $delimiter = !empty($_POST['delimiter']) ? $_POST['delimiter'] : false;

                // Записываем переменные в массив
                foreach ($tmp as $key => $value) {
                    // Автоматически определить как разделитель стоит или стоит он вообще или нет

                    $t = $delimiter != false ? strstr(str_replace(" ", " _ ", $value), $delimiter, true) : $value; 

                    if ( filter_var($t, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
                        file_put_contents($this->tmpFolder, $t."\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);    
                        $count_processed++;
                    } 
                }
                echo "<hr> Найдено емайлов: { $count_processed }";
            } else {
                echo "<p>Пустой массив данных!</p>";
                //var_dump($tmp);
            }


        } else {
            ?>
            <form action="?action=new" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h3>Upload emails</h3>
                <p><textarea name="data2load" cols="45" rows="25" placeholder="Put here emails"></textarea></p>
                <p>
                <label>Разделитель который используется для емайла и пароля</label><br>
                <select name="delimiter">
                    <option value=":">:</option>
                    <option value=";">;</option>
                    <option value="_" selected>Пробел как разделитель</option>
                    <option>Разделителя нету</option>
                </select></p>
                <p>Удалить дубликаты<input type="checkbox" name="removeDublicates" /></p>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Добавить емайлы" />
            </form>
            <?php 
        }
    }

    public function generateEmaildb(){

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

            // Фильтры по умолчанию пустые 
            $begin = false;
            $end   = false;
            $domain= false;

            // имя для сохранения сгенерированной информации пустое
            $fileName = "";

            $recordedEmails = 0;

            if (!empty($_POST['filterBegin'])) {

                $fileName .= $_POST['filterBegin'];
                $begin = true;
            }
            if (!empty($_POST['filterEnd'])) {

                $fileName .= $_POST['filterEnd'];
                $end = true;
            }
            if (!empty($_POST['filterDomen'])) {

                $fileName .= $_POST['filterDomen'];
                $domain = true;
            }

            $fileName = !$fileName ? "generated_automaticaly.txt" : $fileName.".txt";

            $_SESSION['generated'] = $fileName;

            // Файл сохранять по параметрам заданым пользователями . всего 3 видами параметров.

            $tmp = $_SESSION['tmp'];

            if (!$this->checkFiles($tmp)) {
                echo "<p> Файл с базой емайлов отсутсвует</p>";
                return false;
            }

            $tmp = $this->getData($tmp,true);

            if (!$tmp)
                return false;

            foreach ($tmp as $key => $value) {

                $recordEmail = true;

                // Проверяем фильтры указанные пользователем, если хоть один указанный пользователем не сработал
                // то запись не записывается !!!
                if ($begin != false) {
                    if ($value{0} != mb_strtoupper($begin,'UTF-8') || $value{0} != mb_strtolower($begin,'UTF-8') ) {
                        $recordEmail = false;
                    }
                }
                if ($end != false) {

                    $m = strstr($value, "@", true);
                    if (substr($m, -1) != mb_strtoupper($end,'UTF-8') || substr($m, -1) != mb_strtolower($end,'UTF-8')) {
                        $recordEmail = false;
                    }

                }
                if ($domain != false) {
                    //"^[d|D]\S*@[g|G]?[m|M][a|A][i|I][l|L].[r|R][u|U]$" // для preg_match
                    if (strstr($value, '@') != '@'.mb_strtolower($domain,'UTF-8')) {
                        $recordEmail = false;
                    }
                }

                // Записываем в файл отфильтрованное значение
                if ($recordEmail != false) {
                    file_put_contents($fileName, $value."\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
                    $recordedEmails++;
                }
            }

            echo "<p>Записей { $recordedEmails } в файле { $fileName } </p>";
            echo "<p><form action='?download=getFile' method='POST' target='_blank'><input type='submit' name='downloadFile' value='Скачать файл' /></form></p>";

        } else {

            $tmp = $this->checkFiles($_SESSION['tmp'],true);
            if (!$tmp) {
                echo "<p>Сперва нужно создать базу с емайлами</a>";
            } else {
            ?>
                <form action="?action=gen" method="POST" >
                    <h3>Параметры для генерации базы емайлов</h3>
                    <label>Пустые поля игнорируются!</label>
                    <p><input type="text" name="filterBegin" placeholder="Первый символ емайла. Пр: A,*,a,_" /></p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="filterEnd" placeholder="Последний символ до значка @. Пр: A,*,a,_" /></p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="filterDomen" placeholder="Укажите домен для фильтрации" /></p>
                    <input type="submit" name="genFilterDB" value="Сгенерировать базу"> <br><span style="color: red">OR</span> <br>
                    <input type="submit" name="removeDublicate" value="Удалить дубликаты">
                </form>
                <?php 
            }
        }
    }

    public function sendEmailDestination(){

        // Проверяем файл на существование

        $tmp = $this->getData($_SESSION['generated']);

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && count($tmp) > 0) {

            if ( empty($_POST['from']) or empty($_POST['subject']) or empty($_POST['content'])) {
                echo "<p>Есть пустые поля! Не могу продолжать, выхожу из скрипта</p>";
                return false;
            }

            $sendFrom    = $_POST['from'];
            $sendSubject = $_POST['subject'];
            $sendContent = $_POST['content'];           

            $emailsended = 0;

            foreach ($tmp as $key => $value) {

                //mail::sendMail($value, $sendSubject, $sendContent, $sendFrom);
                $emailsended++;
            }

            echo "<p>Кол-во емайлов отправленно: { $emailsended }</p>";

        } else {

            if (!$tmp) {
                echo "<h3 style='color: green;'>Cперва нужно сгенерировать файл-базу емайлов!</h3>";
            } else {
                ?>
                <form>
                    <p><input type="text" name="from" placeholder="Автор: ваш емайл" /></p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Тема сообщения" /></p>    
                    <p><textarea name="content" placeholder="Тело сообщения" cols="45" rows="25"></textarea></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отослать письма сгенерированной базе!" /></p>  
                </form>
                <?php           
            }
        }

    }

    public function removeDublicate() { 

        $tmp = $_SESSION['temp'];

        $tmp = $this->getData($tmp,true);


        foreach ($tmp as $key => $value_result) {

        }
    }



    public function getFile($what2download=false) {

        $file = $_SESSION['generated'];

        if (isset($_GET['download']) && $file != false) {

            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            readfile($file);
        }
    }


}
```

Помогите мне исправить недочеты  и быдло код